# How can I parse xml coming from http server using android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing the XML Response in an Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706821/parsing-the-xml-response-in-an-android-application)

I am using following code

```
     public void executeHttpGet() throws Exception {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        // set a message text
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");

        // show it
        dialog.show();
         BufferedReader in = null;

         DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
         String url=   "http://newdev.objectified.com/morris/interface/mobile.php?method=dealerLogin&username=zzzzz&password=zzzz";

         String login = "zzzzz";
         String pass = "zzzzz";

         client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("newdev.objectified.com", 80), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(login, pass));

         request.setURI(new URI(url));
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

                in = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";
                String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + NL);
                }
                in.close();
                String page = sb.toString();
                Toast.makeText(this, page, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             //  dialog.dismiss();


        }
```

Now I want to parse the coming xml 
which is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
 <sid>kjdci120ts32e30akcj42acaf0</sid>
  <dnumber>dealer</dnumber>
 <dtitle>Test User</dtitle>
  <dcity>karachi</dcity>
  <dprovince>sindh</dprovince>

  <dcountry></dcountry>
  </response>
```

Please help

Comment: Do research first. Here's [how you parse a XML file](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/). The people here won't do that for you. If you have a specific problem while parsing, you will be supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SAX](http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.xml.parsers/BasicSax.html), or the [DOM](http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.xml.parsers/BasicDom.html), or the [`XmlPullParser`](http://xmlpull.org/), all of which are available in Android.

Comment: Please consider revising [your answers containing links to exampledepot.com](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A115145+url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexampledepot.com*%22) (there's also one hit with [www](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A115145+url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.exampledepot.com*%22)) by either fixing the link to point to the official resource (in this case, from Android itself), or by replacing the link to a more reliable community-controlled resource (e.g. Wikipedia or even another SO answer), or by just removing the link.